# Accessing an array without static references in another class (OOP)

Tags: arrays, oop, pointers, haxe

I'm new to object-oriented-programming, and I have set a strict goal for myself for my current project which is not using static variables. In the process I will try to learn about OOP.

I'm using the Haxe language and it's one of the best languages I've ever seen.

I know a bit about C pointers, and that pointers only store the address of a variable so its pretty much the same variable, just taking up less space (especially for large variables).

Now back to the present, I want to have pointer references to an array of objects of one class because

- I want these objects to interact with each other,
- and I don't want to have any static references,
- and I don't want to have *every* object holding a copy of that array.

How should I go along accessing this array?
Or is there another OOP design pattern or something?

Please correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure you have as firm a handle on pointers as you think.  A pointer doesn't result in taking up less space, it is a different way of referencing the memory.  If you have a character string, for example, whether your reference to it is a pointer or a static variable, the string takes up the same amount of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many questions in this brief.

You can just pass along a context along all your variables, it will be passed by pointer

```
class Context{
    var level:Level=null;
    var enemies:Array<Enemy>=[];
}

class Enemy{
    var ctx:Context;
    function new(ctx){ this.ctx=ctx; }
}

class Main{
    static function main(){
        new Game(new Context());
    }
}
```

and in game, pass along the context to everyone :

```
new Enemy(ctx);
```

etc...

Frankly it is often easier to use static for contexts, like

```
class Context{
    static var level:Level;
}
```

But that's up to you :)

As a side note, all non primitives are pointers to structure (ex arrays) just like java.

Comment: Okay, so the 'Context' class is a class that stores all the game variables, and any objects in the game should access the vars via the 'Context' that got passed through, right?

Comment: That's It. Game data storage is very static by nature. You can also use split contexts but it is a matter of how big your game is.